# Highcharts add 3 buttons Hide/Remove/Settings to Legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I would like to add 3 buttons(Hide/Remove/Settings) to the Legend:

1. Hide button should have onclick event to hide series/indicator,
2. Remove button should have onclick event to remove(not hide) series/indicator,
3. Settings button should have onclick event to show popup for edit settings of the series/indicator.

Code:

```
legend: {
  enabled: true,
  useHTML:true,
  labelFormatter: function () {
    return this.name + ' <button onclick="indicator_hide()">Hide</button>' + '<button onclick="indicator_remove()">Remove</button>' + '<button onclick="indicator_settings()">Settings</button>';
}
```

Code for button

```
function indicator_hide(){
  if(chart.series[0].visible==true){ 
    chart.series[0].visible=false
  } else{
    chart.series[0].visible=true
  }
}
```

I created a chart, see the link below.

jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/PaulJaker/7bLdjs4y/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to connect the click events with a series if you use `load` chart event to add event listeners. Then it is enough to call the right methods for a series.

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      this.legend.allItems.forEach(item => {
        const btns = item.legendItem.element.children;

        btns[0].addEventListener('click', () => indicator_hide(item));
        btns[1].addEventListener('click', () => indicator_remove(item));
        btns[2].addEventListener('click', () => indicator_settings(item));
      });

      document.getElementById('popupClose').addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.parentElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
      });
    }
  }
},
legend: {
  enabled: true,
  useHTML: true,
  labelFormatter: function() {
    return this.name + ' <button>Toggle</button>' +
      '<button>Remove</button>' +
      '<button>Settings</button>';
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bu53n1sc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: Hi ppotaczek, 
thank you for valuable informations.
I tried to use Highcharts original "Edit popUp" for edit paramters of Indicators, 
I updated "function indicator_settings" as below, but It doesn't working.


function indicator_settings(series) {
  if (!this.chart.indicatorsPopupContainer) {
            this.chart.indicatorsPopupContainer = document
              .getElementsByClassName('highcharts-popup-indicators')[0];
            this.chart.indicatorsPopupContainer.style.display = 'block';
  }
 }

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/PaulJaker/7bLdjs4y/11/

Paul
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Pauljaker, Which original edit popup do you mean? And how do you want to handle series?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, 
I mean, when I want to add indicator. I click on Indicator button from StoockTools, then the Indicator PopUp will show with section "Add/Edit". I can add indicator, for example EMA with period 14. Then when I want to update parameter (period of EMA), I need to click to indicator button..then popUp will show, I go to Edit section, click to indicator and there I can update parameters. I would like to have the button for edit parameters of added indicators in the legend. And after click I can edit the parameters of specific indicator directly.  Thanks. Paul

Comment: Hello, It seems to be enough if you trigger `click` event on the buttons. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wkLa6n0y/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, let me appology I'm newbie and I still learning to setup highcharts. I'm appreciate your support. I found 2 issues,which I have problem to solve:


a. When I using remove button for indicator,which is on another pane(below chart), then the indicator is removed,but the indicator pane still stayed on the chart. Have Highchart another function for indicator removing with the indicator pane as well?

Comment: b. When I add new indicator (with using stocktools indicator button),the added buttons don't working,there are missing "addEventListener" for buttons. I tried to solve...I changed the "chart.event" from load to render, then the event working, but this caused infinite loop for adding "addEventListener" for each button. How can I add 3 buttons to indicator only one time through stocktools indicator button? 

Thank you.
Paul

Comment: 1. In this case youu need to also remove y-axis and call `resizeYAxes` method. 2. Use `afterAnimate` event instead. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rgmLnavd/

Comment: HI @ppotaczek, 
you are clever man. Thank you a lot for your great support. I want to give you a like, but  I have low reputation so far, I will do later. 
Once again, thank you...